# Can I set additional parameters of spring boot with groovy?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-security

I am new to groovy and spring boot.I start to work on login with spring boot.
I need to pass two additional parameters to the **CustomAuthToken** class.
I can pass only one.When I assign other variable to some value auth fail.

This is my code.

CustomAuthFilter.groovy

```
Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (!request.post) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("not supported: $request.method")
    }
    String username = (obtainUsername(request) ?: '').trim()
    String password = (obtainPassword(request) ?: '').trim()
    String extrafield1 = request.getParameter("extrafield1")
    String extrafield2 = request.getParameter("extrafield2")


        def authentication = new CustomAuthToken(username, password, extrafield1, null, false, false, false)

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false)
    if (session || getAllowSessionCreation()) {
        request.session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY'] = TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(username)
    }

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication)
}
```

CustomAuthToken.groovy

```
CustomAuthToken(Object principal, Object credentials, String extrafield1, String PVM, Boolean isAccept, Boolean isLogEnabled, Boolean is3PLEnabled) {
    super(principal, credentials)
    extra1 = extrafield1
}
```

It is working and I can access the extra1 field.
But when I try to pass anther parameter it's not working.

```
CustomAuthToken(Object principal, Object credentials, String extrafield1, String extrafield2, String PVM, Boolean isAccept, Boolean isLogEnabled, Boolean is3PLEnabled) {
    super(principal, credentials)
    extra1 = extrafield1
    extra2 = extrafield2
}
```

When I try this extra2 is passing. But auth is fail.
Can anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that

```
CustomAuthToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

If that's the case, you need to change the [`super`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java?ts=4#L48-L77) constructor call from

```
super(principal, credentials)
```

to

```
super(principal, credentials, Collections.emptyList())
```

You see, the constructor you are invoking sets `authenticated=false`

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
    super(null);
    this.principal = principal;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    setAuthenticated(false);
}
```

So you want to invoke the correct constructor

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);
    this.principal = principal;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
}
```

Comment: You can view both the constructors [online](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java?ts=4#L48-L77)

Comment: Thanks for the answering.I will try this one

Comment: @IshaS Please upvote the answer if you find it useful. That gives me the points and I can help further in the future.

Comment: I upvoted because answer gives me lots of information and found original constrictors from your comment. But this solution doesn't fix my issue.Thanks for helping me.

Comment: maybe post a link to a sample that demonstrates your problem. ie, there is probably more than one thing going wrong. `Authentication.isAuthenticated` returning false is possibly just one of your issues. But definitely an issue